# Как правильно написать POST запрос для Point?

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, десериализация

Есть сущность

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.serialization.GeometryDeserializer;
import com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.serialization.GeometrySerializer;
//....
@Entity
@Data
public class ParkingPlace {

//....
    @NotNull
    @Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry")
    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    private com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point coordinate;
//....

    public ParkingPlace() {
    }
}
```

Использую spring boot.

Есть REST контроллер, который пока только выдает элемент сущности из базы и по идее должен в неё записать новую.

```
@PostMapping
public ParkingPlace post(ParkingPlace place){
    return service.savePlace(place);
}
```

Не пойму как мне правильно отправть POST запрос (а точнее составить тело запроса, чтобы этот запрос десериализовался в сущность с полем coordinate).

Когда послыаю запрос без поля coordinate, то запрос обрабатывается и создается объект (но соответственно поле coordinate = null).

При попытке хоть как то задать координаты в эту сущность сервер пишет ошибку

```
Field error in object 'parkingPlace' on field 'coordinate': rejected value [coordinates:POINT(623.1214, 12.623462346)]; codes [typeMismatch.parkingPlace.coordinate,typeMismatch.coordinate,typeMismatch.com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [parkingPlace.coordinate,coordinate]; arguments []; default message [coordinate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point' for property 'coordinate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point' for property 'coordinate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

Пробовал писать запрос по разному, никак не получается.

GET запрос выдает такую сущность

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "coordinate": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            4.124,
            112.1213
        ]
    },
    "isFree": false,
    "area": {
        "id": 27,
        "name": " Wall Streat",
        "freeSpaceCount": 2
    }
}
```

Как мне правильно написать тело POST запроса для моего случая?

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае всё зависит от *GeometryDeserializer.class*, если он настроен так, чтобы десериализовать объект сериализованный *GeometrySerializer.class*, то в теле POST достаточно будет передать:

```
{
    "coordinate": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            4.124,
            112.1213
        ]
    }
}
```